# Android ViewModel unit test : RxJava onSuccess gives nullPointerException

Tags: android, unit-testing, mockito, rx-java2

I'm trying to unit test my viewModel class but when I run the test I get a `NullPointerException` in my disposable `OnSuccess` Method and I don't understand why. Because of this the method that I test always returns null.

Here is my code for my test class `CityListViewModelTest.kt`:

```
@RunWith(JUnit4::class)
class CityListViewModelTest {

    @Rule
    @JvmField
    val rule = InstantTaskExecutorRule()

    @Mock
    private lateinit var repository: ForecastRepository

    @InjectMocks
    private lateinit var viewModel: CityListViewModel


    @Before @Throws fun setUp(){
        RxAndroidPlugins.setInitMainThreadSchedulerHandler{Schedulers.trampoline()}
RxJavaPlugins.setIoSchedulerHandler { Schedulers.trampoline() }

        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this)

    }

    @Test
    fun getCities() {
        val response = getMockedCities(5)

        `when`(repository.getCities(ArgumentMatchers.anyDouble(), ArgumentMatchers.anyDouble()))
            .thenReturn(Single.just(response))

        val result = viewModel.getCities(0.0,0.0)

        verify(repository).getCities(0.0,0.0)
        verify(repository).getCache() //should be called but isn't

        assertEquals(response.list,result.value) //result.value should be a list of 5 mocked cities but is null

    }

    fun getMockedCities(count : Int) : OpenWeatherCycleDataResponse {
        val cities = ArrayList<City>()
        for (i in 0..count) {
            val city = mock(City::class.java)
            cities.add(city)
        }
        return OpenWeatherCycleDataResponse(cities)
    }
}
```

And my viewModel class `CityListViewModel.kt` :

```
class CityListViewModel @Inject constructor(private var forecastRepo: ForecastRepository):ViewModel() {
    //@Inject lateinit
    var cities : MutableLiveData<List<City>> = MutableLiveData()
    //@Inject lateinit
     var disposable : CompositeDisposable = CompositeDisposable()


    fun getCities(lat: Double,lon:Double): LiveData<List<City>> {
        disposable.add(forecastRepo.getCities(lat,lon).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribeWith(object: DisposableSingleObserver<OpenWeatherCycleDataResponse>(){
                override fun onSuccess(t: OpenWeatherCycleDataResponse) {

                    forecastRepo.getCache().saveCities(t.list)
                    cities.value = t.list
                }

                override fun onError(e: Throwable) {
                    Timber.e(e.localizedMessage)
                }
            }))
        return cities
    }

    fun getCityByName(cityName: String): LiveData<City>{
        val searchedCity = MutableLiveData<City>()
        disposable.add(forecastRepo.getCityByName(cityName).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribeWith(object: DisposableSingleObserver<City>(){
                override fun onSuccess(t: City) {

                    searchedCity.value = t
                    forecastRepo.getCache().saveCities(listOf(t))
                }

                override fun onError(e: Throwable) {
                    Timber.e(e.localizedMessage)
                }
            }))
        return searchedCity
    }

    override fun onCleared() {
        super.onCleared()
        disposable.clear()
    }
}
```

Here are the logs :

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.example.zach.weatherapp.viewModel.CityListViewModel$getCities$1.onSuccess(CityListViewModel.kt:30)
    at com.example.zach.weatherapp.viewModel.CityListViewModel$getCities$1.onSuccess(CityListViewModel.kt:27)
    at io.reactivex.internal.operators.single.SingleObserveOn$ObserveOnSingleObserver.run(SingleObserveOn.java:81)
    at io.reactivex.internal.schedulers.TrampolineScheduler.scheduleDirect(TrampolineScheduler.java:52)
    at io.reactivex.internal.operators.single.SingleObserveOn$ObserveOnSingleObserver.onSuccess(SingleObserveOn.java:64)
    at io.reactivex.internal.operators.single.SingleSubscribeOn$SubscribeOnObserver.onSuccess(SingleSubscribeOn.java:68)
    at io.reactivex.internal.operators.single.SingleJust.subscribeActual(SingleJust.java:30)
    at io.reactivex.Single.subscribe(Single.java:3096)
    at io.reactivex.internal.operators.single.SingleSubscribeOn$SubscribeOnObserver.run(SingleSubscribeOn.java:89)
    at io.reactivex.internal.schedulers.TrampolineScheduler.scheduleDirect(TrampolineScheduler.java:52)
    at io.reactivex.internal.operators.single.SingleSubscribeOn.subscribeActual(SingleSubscribeOn.java:37)
    at io.reactivex.Single.subscribe(Single.java:3096)
    at io.reactivex.internal.operators.single.SingleObserveOn.subscribeActual(SingleObserveOn.java:35)
    at io.reactivex.Single.subscribe(Single.java:3096)
    at io.reactivex.Single.subscribeWith(Single.java:3140)
    at com.example.zach.weatherapp.viewModel.CityListViewModel.getCities(CityListViewModel.kt:27)
    at com.example.zach.weatherapp.viewModel.CityListViewModelTest.getCities(CityListViewModelTest.kt:58)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved by creating by hand a dummy response. getMockedCities() returns an array of City objects with null variables (as expected) but my City object's variables weren't nullable. Also I had to mock the repository.getCache()

Answer (score 0):

As soon as this line gets called:

```
// CityListViewModelTest
val result = viewModel.getCities(0.0,0.0)
```

`CityListViewModel` will subscribe to `forecastRepo.getCities()`, so it makes sense that `verify(repository).getCities(0.0,0.0)` passes.

However it is not guaranteed that `forecastRepo.getCache()` will be called before `verify(repository).getCache()` because `forecastRepo.getCities()` runs on a separate thread. In your test code, you need to use [TestSchedulers](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/io/reactivex/schedulers/TestScheduler.html) to wait for the operation in io scheduler to complete.

Side note:

It seems `.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())` in ViewModels doesn't do much here because ViewModels are independent of Android lifecycles. Instead of using `setValue()`, you can use `postValue()` to update `MutableLiveData` from a background thread.

**Update:**

Try using this:

```
@Rule
@JvmField
val rule = InstantTaskExecutorRule()

@Mock
lateinit var observer: Observer<List<City>>

@Test
fun getCities() {
    val response = getMockedCities(5)

    `when`(repository.getCities(ArgumentMatchers.anyDouble(), ArgumentMatchers.anyDouble()))
        .thenReturn(Single.just(response))

    viewModel.getCities(0.0,0.0).observeForever(observer)

    verify(repository).getCities(0.0,0.0)
    verify(repository).getCache()

    // assertEquals(response.list,result.value) //result.value should be a list of 5 mocked cities but is null
    verify(observer).onChanged(reponse.list)
}
```

Also `getCache()` and `getCache().saveCities()` could be the problem. Try mocking these as well if above code doesn't work.

Comment: I added this line in my setUp() method : 

`RxJavaPlugins.setIoSchedulerHandler { Schedulers.trampoline() }`

Now I don't have errors about  forecastRepo.getCache() not getting called but I still get the NullPointerException in the onSuccess

Comment: I still get the error, I think it comes from the schedulers when I call observeOn subscribeOn but not sure nor know why. See the stackTrace in the updated post above